# HTML5 errors on IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem with internet explorer 8. I´m using modernizr with html5shiv and it´s working apparently well but html5 code is behaving bad. All content that i have into footer goes out.

If I inspect the code...

- Other browsers OK:`<footer id="site_footer"><div id="wrap_footer"></div></footer>`
- IE8 ERROR:`<footer id="site_footer"></footer><div id="wrap_footer"></div>`

What´s happening? i´m going mad!

pd: It´s not a javascript conflict

Thanks!!

Comment: could you show a link? Have you set `display: block` for footer?

Comment: What do you mean "goes out"?

Comment: can you share jsfiddle link?

Comment: That sounds like html5shiv is _not_ “working well”, because it should prevent exactly that from happening. So most likely you have not embedded it correctly, or to late.

Answer (score 0):

You need use [HTML5Shiv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Shiv) technique.

```
<head>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
         <script src="html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- all css code after-->
</head>
```

`IE 8` and early don't understand right the HTML5 tags.
`HTML5Shiv` will just once call `document.createElement` with HTML5 tag name and add to its `default css` via `display: block`.

Comment: It´s works. I have detected the problem. I´m using Wordpress and if i add the script with WP functions (wp_register_script and wp_enqueue_script) is when works bad. If i add "html5shiv" in normal mode it´s works well... someone knows why?

Thanks!!